# Excel multi tiered lists in data validatation using alphanumeric fields

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu

I am using multi tiered lists  and data validation   and have  an issue when the fields are alpha numeric

eg

```
Col 1               Col 2
100 Dairy           101 Milk
                    102 Cheese
200 Bakery          201 Bread
                    202 Cake
```

If you choose  `100 Dairy` in the drop down list Col1    Col2 will not give the 2 fields to choose from    however  if you remove one of the sets of numbers   then data validation will provide the 2 options in col 2

In Column 2  Data validation  I am using  `=Indirect(A1)`

How can I have both Number and letters in both of my drop down lists

Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A Name (named range) cannot start with a digit or contain spaces.  So, in your validation formula, you have to change your entry in column A into the actual name that is being used for your dependent dropdown.

If you used the Excel Create Name wizard, then something like:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" " & $A$1," ","_"))
```

That will only work if **ALL** of your dependent lists start with a digit.  If not, you will need a different algorithm.

eg:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(-LEFT($A$1))," ","")&$A$1," ","_"))
```

If you made up your own names, again, you will need a different algorithm.